# I'm trying to calculate the center point of my eye using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv

My program can detect my left eye, but I want it to be able to place a dot around on the center of the detected area. I tried to calculate it but it always places the dot near the upper left hand corner. Any Ideas/Help would be appreciated.

```
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # sets up webcam

while 1:  # capture frame, converts to greyscale, looks for faces
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # draws box around face
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + int(w / 2), y + int(h / 2)), (255, 0, 0), 2)  # Draws Box Around Face
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + int(h / 2), x:x + int(w / 2)]  # slices grey area based off given parameters
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]  # selects region of interest (roi) based on color
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)  # looks for eyes
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:  # draws boxes around eyes
            eye_centerX = (ex+(ex+ew))/2
            eye_centerY = (ey+(ey+eh))/2
            eye_center_cord = eye_centerX, eye_centerY
            cv2.line(img, (int(eye_centerX), int(eye_centerY)), (int(eye_centerX), int(eye_centerY)), (0, 0, 0), 10)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the eye detector module works for one eye at a time. Even if you see two eyes being boxed in the image, that for loop is actually related with **one eye**.

The solution would be to **separate the face box into two parts** and **detect the left and right eyes separately by looking coordinates**.

If the explanation is not clear enough, I can explain it by editing your code. Just say it .

Here is the edited code:

```
import cv2
left_eye_point_x = 0
right_eye_point_x = 0
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # sets up webcam

while 1:  # capture frame, converts to greyscale, looks for faces
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # draws box around face
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + int(w / 2), y + int(h / 2)), (255, 0, 0), 2)  #
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + int(h / 2), x:x + int(w / 2)]  
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]  
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)  # looks for eyes
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:  # draws boxes around eyes
           if (ex+ey)/2 < (x+y)/2:
                left_eye_point_x = (ex+ey)/2
            elif (ex+ey)/2 > (x+y)/2:
                right_eye_point_x = (ex+ey)/2
            cv2.line(img, (int(left_eye_point_x), int(right_eye_point_x)), (int(left_eye_point_x), int(right_eye_point_x)), (0, 0, 0), 10)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But could you maybe edit the code?

Comment: Thank so much! The code works and I understand what I was doing wrong!

Comment: Not to sound rude, but I think there is a problem with your code. I think the issue is that my code already only detects one eye as opposed to detecting both.

Comment: I was in rush sorry about that maybe the cv2.line is in wrong place but you got the what was wrong about